# Load files globally in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

i am new to react native. I was wondering is there anyway to load CSS,Colors globally to all components and screens rather then importing in each screen.

I have one reusable stylesheet.js and colors.js which contain all global css and colors.
**stylesheet.js**

```
'use strict';

import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import colors from './colors';


module.exports = StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        flex:1,
    },

    alwaysred: {
       color:colors.txt_main,
    },

});
```

But now to use in components i need to import in every component.
So i was wondering if there is more easy way to import the stylesheet and colors to all scrrens/components.

I tried to importing in index.js ,but then when i tried to access style property it saying style undefined
Something like this

**Index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import stylesheet from './app/resources/styles/stylesheet';

import App from './app/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('newApp', () => App);
```

**App.js**

```
 <Text style={stylesheet.alwaysred}>
     New stylesheet imported globally
  </Text>
```

This giving error saying undefined stylesheet.
I have folloed this Stackoverflow thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853178/react-native-global-styles) to create global stylesheet

Comment: > it saying style undefined
That's because you use different module implementations. You export in `node.js` style, but import it with implementation from standart. So, just export styles with `export default` instead of `module.exports`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `global`:

```
global.stylesheet = StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        flex:1,
    },

    alwaysred: {
       color:colors.txt_main,
    },

});
```

Comment: Hey! This works, but it's really not the best practice. By defining variables on `global` makes it harder for other developers and tools like type checkers, bundlers etc. to use your code. If you must have a "global" style, it's usually a better idea to define a "theme.js" (or similar file) explicitly to import where you want to use it.

Comment: @jevakallio agreed, any global statement is very delicate to use. I prefer to use modules and "haste" module system, for example.  
But topic starter wants to get global access, I just helped)

Comment: Cool. Just wanted to log the comment here in case someone comes by later and sees the solution :)

Comment: @jevakallio yes i have a a file names stylesheet.js separetly and i am loading it globally rather then importing in each screen. Kirill answer is what i was looking for. thank you kirill :))

Comment: @user7747472 cool! Happy you found a solution for your problem. It's not really what you're *supposed* to do, but hey, the rules are made up and the points don't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical React way of achieving this is creating your own styled, components. For example, if you wanted all the `Text` elements in your application to be red, you can define your own component for it:

```
// Text.js
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const StyledText = ({ style, ...props }) => (
  <Text style={[styles.text, style]} {...props}></Text>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});

export default StyledText;
```

And then you can use that text component where you'd normally use `Text` from react-native:

```
import Text from 'Text';
```

This is a little verbose, so often people use libraries like [glamorous-native](https://github.com/robinpowered/glamorous-native) or [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to achieve the same effect.

```
// glamorous
const MyStyledText = glamorous.text({
  color: 'red'
});

// styled-components
const MyStyledText = styled.Text`
  color: red;
`;
```

Comment: Yes, i have seperate stylesheet js, but i dont like the idea of importing importing in each screen. Lets say i have 10 screen i need to load text.js in each 10 screen, but instead i wanted to make it global so all its variable accessible to all screen. Kilrlin ans is the one what i was looking . I like this method too. I will use it too