# React Native: Inherit styles

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am starting this path to learn react native development. On each screen I can set styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```

How Can I set global styles and be able to use them in all screens?

I was thinking in passing it as props, but it does not seem practical to do it that way.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native global styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853178/react-native-global-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global style, and use it without importing it, you only import it in your main screen.

```
// global styles Global.js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

module.GlobalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

if (global) {
  global.GlobalStyles = module.GlobalStyles;
}
```

Then in your main screen / entry point

```
import './Global';
```

Use it like

```
<View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/global-variable-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

Create a **styles.js** file and paste your stylesheet there as

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    padding: 20,
    textAlign: 'center'
}
})
```

Import the above style in your component as

```
import styles from 'styles.js'
```

Then you can use it like

```
<View style={styles.container}/>
```