# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: styles

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my react-native project I experienced the above error

**My App.js file:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

//Screens

import Header from './Shared/Header'

import ProductContainer from './Screens/Products/ProductContainer'

export default function App() {

  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Header />

      <ProductContainer />

    </View>

  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {

    flex: 1,

    backgroundColor: '#fff',

    alignItems: 'center',

    justifyContent: 'center',

  },

});
```

**My ProductCotainer.js file:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList} from 'react-native'

import ProductList from './ProductList';

const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');

const ProductContainer = () => {

    const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        setProducts(data);

        return () => {

            setProducts([])

        }

    }, [])

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Product Container</Text>

            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList 

                data={products}

                numColumns={2}

                renderItem={({item}) => <ProductList 

                key={item.id}

                item={item}/>}

                keyExtractor={item => item.name}

            />

            </View>

        </View>

    )

}

export default ProductContainer;
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: you did not define `styles` in the `ProductCotainer.js` file

Comment: @CornelRaiu Right and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the `styles` in the `ProductCotainer.js` file.
In order to use the styles you have 2 options:

1. Define it in each file that uses it. Which can be pretty hard to maintain in case of a medium/large app that has lots of common styles.
2. Define a style file that gets imported in each file that uses the styles. [This would be a good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853178/react-native-global-styles)

Comment: actually I want to use different styles for my project so can you once tell me how to define styles in ProductContainer.js

Comment: exactly the way you did it in App.js